# Pdf sharp differences between local and server application

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp

I created application to print labels using pdf sharp. Problem is that in the local machine i have got other labels then on the server machine. Of course, i want labels like in the local.

[image]

But in the server i have got something like:

[image]

I was trying resolving this issue, by changing font. Very interesting fact is, that some fonts are working great, some not...

I also trying to configure pdf sharp, changing ScaleTransform, FontFamilies, reinstals fonts, changing XStringFormats.. But nothing helps me.

Anyone knows, how to resolve the issue?

Comment: All the fonts you use in PDFSharp must be installed on the server also (in `c:\windows\fonts`).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I installed all fonts which i am using. Application get this font, but returns it a liitle bti different. I mean that letters spacing are different between server and local

Comment: What kind of font are you using? And I think a restart of the server is needed for the new font to be usable in IIS, but not 100% sure about that.

Comment: I am using Gloucester MT Extra Condensed, Regular. I was not trying to restart the server, but it is not possible for now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer VDWWD. Restart windows server resolved my problem.

Many thanks :)